# Django CSS elements not aligning as expected

Tags: css, django-templates

I created a html file with headers, banners, footers that is given below..I'm tring to align the navigation link but for some reason its not aligning inline. The problem is with the Navigation id.
Any help would be of great help.

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "XHTML1-s.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head> 
     <title>DJANGO E-Commerce website</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
     <title>{% block title %}{% if page_title %}{{ page_title }} - {% endif %} ?     
          {{ site_name }}{% endblock %}</title> 
     <meta name="keywords" content="{{ meta_keywords }}" /> 
     <meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}" />
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css.css" />
     <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/css.css"
        type="text/css" />  -->

    <!--<script src="/site_media/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head> 
<body> 
    {% block site_wrapper %}{% endblock %} 
</body>
</html>
```

catalog.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block site_wrapper %} 
<div id="main"> 
     <a href="#content" class="skip_link">Skip to main content</a> 
     <div id="banner"> 
          <div class="bannerIEPadder"> 
               <div class="cart_box"> 
                [link to cart here] 
                </div>
              Modern Musician 
          </div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="navigation"> 
          <div class="navIEPadder"> 
                {% include "tags/navigation.html" %}
          </div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="middle"> 
          <div id="sidebar"> 
               <div class="sidebarIEPadder"> 
                [search box here] 
               <br /> 
                {% include "tags/category_list.html" %} 
               </div> 
          </div> 
          <div id="content"> 
               <a name="content"></a> 
               <div class="contentIEPadder"> 
                    {% block content %}{% endblock %} 
               </div> 
          </div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="footer"> 
          <div class="footerIEPadder"> 
               [footer here] 
           </div> 
     </div> 
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

Navigation.html

```
<u1>
    <li><a href="/catalog/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/">Contact</a></li>
</u1>
<div class="cb"></div>
```

css.css

```
*{ 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}

html{ 
    font-size:medium; 
} 

html,body{ 
    background-color:Blue;
}

.cb{ 
    clear:both; 
} 

.fr{ 
    float:right; 
}

.fl{ 
    float:left; 
}

.bn{ 
    border:none; 
}

#main{ 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width:900px; 
     background-color:White; 
} 

.bannerIEPadder, .sidebarIEPadder, .contentIEPadder{ 
     padding:10px;  
}

.navIEPadder, .footerIEPadder{ 
     padding:5px; 
}

#banner{ 
     width:900px; 
     height:75px; 
     background-color:DarkOrange; 
     color:White; 
     font-size:36px; 
     font-weight:bold; 
     position:relative; 
}

div.cart_box{ 
     position:absolute; 
     top:20px; 
     right:10px; 
     font-size:medium; 
}

div.cart_box a{ 
     color:white; 
} 

#sidebar{ 
     width:200px; 
     float:left;
}

#content{ 
     width:700px; 
     float:left; 
}

#footer{ 
     clear:both; 
     background-color:#98AC5E; 
     color:White; 
     text-align:center; 
}

a.skip_link{ 
     position:absolute; 
     left:-1000px; 
     top:-1000px; 
} 

#navigation ul{
    list-style-type:None;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#navigation ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:inline;
}

#navigation ul li a{
    color:White;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    display:inline;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover{
    color:#616161;
    background-color:Red;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a{ 
     color:#98AC5E; 
     font-weight:bold; 
     text-decoration:none; 
} 
a:hover{ 
     text-decoration:underline; 
} 

/* category page styles */ 
div.product_thumbnail{ 
     text-align:center; 
     float:left; 
     width:150px; 
     height:200px; 
} 

/* product page styles */ 
div.product_image{ 
     float:left; 
     padding:0 10px 10px 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have display:inline on your Li's.

You should also put float:left on the 'a' tags within your nav UL's and remove the display:inline on them.

You could also put overflow:auto on the class 'navIEPadder'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: THanks for the response..The problem was the declaration of my unordered list instead of UL I did U1...